# Class Library Project Form Members Unavailable

Tags: .net, winforms

What am I missing. I created a class library project in .NET, added a form and public property 'foo' to the form's code. I cannot access the foo property from the Class1.

Image of foo not accessable:

[image: Image of foo not accessable]

Comment: Please update the question to include code and errors as formatted text, not as links to images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the variable `f` is of type `System.Windows.Forms.Form`, *not* of type `ClassLibrary1.Form1`.  And `Form` has no member called `foo`.

The variable may be referencing an instance of type `Form1`, but the variable itself is of type `Form`.  (And thus can hold references to any child class of `Form`.)

Make the variable of type `Form1` to access its members:

```
Form1 f = new Form1();
```

or more simply:

```
var f = new Form1();
```

---

If you want to keep the variable of type `Form` for some other reason, you can specify the type when dereferencing it:

```
(f as Form1).foo = "";
```

Note that the `as` operation will evaluate to `null` if the type doesn't match at runtime.